# How to avoid declaring variable outside of enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, scope

I want to avoid using variable **index** outside of enhanced for loop as it is useless after the loop and pollutes the namespace but cannot find my way around it.

**Problem**

```
int index = 0;        // I want to avoid using this variable outside the loop
for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets) {
    for (int el : bucket) {
        a[index++] = el;
    }
}
```

**Whole Code**

```
package sort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BucketSort {
    private BucketSort() {
    }

    private static int getMax(int[] a) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int el : a) {
            max = Math.max(max, el);
        }

        return max;
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a, int k) {
        int M = getMax(a) + 1;

        List<List<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            buckets.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        for (int el : a) {
            int bucketIndex = (int) Math.floor(k * (double) el / M);
            buckets.get(bucketIndex).add(el);
        }

        for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets) {
            Collections.sort(bucket);
        }

        int index = 0;
        for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets) {
            for (int el : bucket) {
                a[index++] = el;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One user on a similar question, suggested that a way to avoid the "useless variable" would be to wrap another block around the whole lot for local scoping

```
{
    int index = 0;        
    for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets) {
        for (int el : bucket) {
            a[index++] = el;
        }
    }
}
```

but I am not so sure about it.

Comment: Move to a well-named private method.  (Same for the other loops so it's clear what each step is supposed to do without having to read the code.)

Comment: trying to hide the index will be much more complex than just using fori

Comment: Why are you worrying about this?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel quoting from one of the answers, "However, I understand the desire to avoid this since future-developer may infer that it is being used elsewhere."

Comment: I don't see that as a valid concern IMHO, or otherwise it means your method is doing too much and needs to be broken up into multiple methods.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you are right. It needs to be in a separate method. Thats why I have accepted the answer that suggests to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick it in a method to hide any local variables.

```
private void copy(int[] a, List<List<Integer>> buckets) {
    int index = 0;
    for (List<Integer> bucket : buckets) {
        for (int el : bucket) {
            a[index++] = el;
        }
    }
}
```

But you are trying to avoid a very common situation that even the best of coders have to accept. I would just leave it as it is or throw the `{}` around it as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use streams:

```
a = buckets.stream().flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Note that you have to use Java 8 or above to use the streams API.

Comment: also Note that this is resulting in a new array, which will be lost when returning from that method, that is, nothing got sorted (Java is pass-by-value)

Comment: @user85421 good point, the method would have to be changed to return the array instead of void.

Comment: @roksui since Java 21 just came out I hope there aren't many people who still aren't even on Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is nothing actually wrong with creating the variable outside the loop.  However, I understand the desire to avoid this since future-developer may infer that it is being used elsewhere.

1. Use traditional for loop. Your List is an ArrayList so iterating by index isn't a problem.
2. Move the logic into a separate method so the scope of the variable is obviously limited
3. Use the Stream API as shown in the answer from @wannaBeDev